# How can I have a git package dependency in pubspec.yaml that works on Windows and macOS

Tags: flutter, git, dart, package, yaml

I have created a dart package for common functionality that I use between different Flutter apps.

The package is hosted on a local file server. My main development machine runs Windows, so I've set up my pubspec.yaml file in my app as follows:

```yaml
dependencies:
  my_common_lib:
    git:
      url: \\my_file_server\packages\pub\my_common_lib
      ref: master
```

Now I want to continue development on macOS (and switch back and forth to Windows). However, when I run `pub get` on my macOS development machine, I get the following error:

```
stderr: fatal: repository '\\my_file_server\packages\pub\my_common_lib' does not exist
```

I have my file server mounted on macOS under `/Volumes`, so obviously I could change the path to `/Volumes/packages/pub/my_common_lib`. That wouldn't work on Windows though.
I've also tried `smb://my_file_server/packages/pub/my_common_lib`, as that's what "Show Details" in Finder reveals the path is, but that also doesn't work on Windows.

So basically what I'm after is either:

- A path to my file server that would work on both Windows and macOS.
- A way to tell Pub where to look for the package on Windows and on macOS with a variable for the server address.
- An alternative solution

PS: The path to my file server is arbitrary of course, but I think it still gets the point across.

Comment: At a program level (not the command-line), forward slashes and backslashes are identical.  So you can have a forward-slash path that is interpreted correctly for both Windows and Unix.